# Preprocessor macro expansion to another preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, expansion, preprocessor-directive

Initially I thought I needed this, but I eventually avoided it. However, my curiosity (and appetite for knowledge, hum) make me ask:

Can a preprocessor macro, for instance in

```
#include "MyClass.h"

INSTANTIATE_FOO_TEMPLATE_CLASS(MyClass)
```

expand to another include, like in

```
#include "MyClass.h"

#include "FooTemplate.h"
template class FooTemplate<MyClass>;
```

?

Comment: One day you will want to transfer your code to an OS like Linux where case is significant (i.e. Foo.h and foo.h are two different files) and then all the misspellings that are not caught on Windows will come home to roost. alternatively, if you are a Linux person, you will one day want to go the other way, with different but equally horrible problems.

Comment: I agree with the always-lowercase rule for file names. I wrote that this way because I wanted to exclude the issue of lowercase conversion (class name -> file name). But that is worth to mention, thanks. +1!

Comment: Our rule is that filenames match exactly the naming scheme for our types and functions.  We do exactly as the Questioner here, a type name FooType will be defined in FooType.h.  As with any "style" guideline, choose a style and stick with it.  Having said that we develop heavily on linux and so this rule is automatically enforced for us by the OS....hmmmmm.....

Comment: Ok. That was an error. I don't like having uppercases in file names, but I like having uppercases in type names. But I should have written both lowercase just for the question.

@Richard Corden: Having the filesystem and compiler enforce the rule may be temporary, and any port to other OSs erases completely this security. At least, with a totalitarian lowercase file name rule, risky behaviour and errors are immediately visible, before any problem has occured. Which I prefer.

Comment: @moala.  Thinking about this a bit more, it struck me that no matter what you do (lower case or mixed case matching contents) it will need to be enforced by some external utility.  There's always the chance that someone will make a mistake and unless you have OS support (as in my case) then you have to check this via some script/tool.  It's easier to check for all lower case - but it's not that difficult to check that the name matches at least one identifier in the file either.  < blatent plug > And you may even have a static analysis tool that does the work for you!!! ;) < / blatent plug >.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that cannot be done, this is because the pre-processor is **single pass**. So it cannot emit other preprocessor directives.

Specifically, from the C99 Standard (6.10.3.4 paragraph 3):

> 3 The resulting completely
>   macro-replaced preprocessing token
>   sequence is not processed as a
>   preprocessing directive even if it
>   resembles one, ...

Interestingly enough, This is why the unary `_Pragma` operator was added to c99. Because `#pragma` could not be emited by macros, but `_Pragma` can.

Comment: Well, it can of course emit the directives. what it cannot do is process them in the same preprocessor pass.

Comment: Since the `#` and `##` characters have special meanings in macros, I don't see how you could actually emit a directive...

Comment: Actually the GCC preprocessor seems to allow "#define X #ifdef X" where the space between the #ifdef and the second X is really a newline, and this actually emits a #ifdef when you run cpp on it. Someone else might like to check this, as I've just had a couple of beers :-)

Comment: Yea, it seems that it is possible to create something that "resembles" a directive, but the standard specifically states (see my edit) that such a construct is not processed as a directive.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't suggesting that the OP  could do what he appears to want.

Answer (score 10):

The C standard says this about preprocessing directives (C99 - 6.10(2) - Preprocessing directives):

> A preprocessing directive consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that begins with
>   a # preprocessing token that (at the start of translation phase 4)
>   ...

and (C99 - 6.10(7)):

> The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro
>   expansion unless otherwise stated.
>
> EXAMPLE In:
>
> ```
> #define EMPTY
> EMPTY # include <file.h>
> ```
>
> the sequence of preprocessing tokens on the second line is not a preprocessing directive, because it does not begin with a # at the start of translation phase 4, even though it will do so after the macro EMPTY has been replaced

So, no, macros cannot expand into a '`#include`' preprocessing directive.  Those directives need to be in place at the start of translation phase 4 (when handling those directives takes place preprocessing happens). Since macro expansion occurs during phase 4, macros can't cause something to exist at the start of phase 4.

I'd like to point out however, that the following **does** work:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define PLATFORM_HEADER "platform/windows/platform.h"
#else
#define PLATFORM_HEADER "platform/linux/platform.h"

#include PLATFORM_HEADER
```

because the C standard says this (C99, 6.10.2(4) - Source file inclusion):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include pp-tokens new-line
> ```
>
> (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. The preprocessing
>   tokens after include in the directive are processed just as in normal text. (Each
>   identifier currently defined as a macro name is replaced by its replacement list of
>   preprocessing tokens.)

Comment: i looked at that part of the standard, but I don't think it is the most relevant section. The example is not one that tries to emit a directive. It is instead an example of a directive which is not preceeded by "whitespace" (even though the EMPTY macro resolves to whitespace).

Comment: I'd agree that your quote from the standard is more directly relevant, but it wan't there when I answered.  Even if the example above isn't the same as what's asked about, the bit about the preprocessing directive needing to be in place at the start of phase 4 also disallows macros from explanding into useful preprocessing directives, even if 6.10.3.4(3) says so more directly. (in other words, even if I don't think my answer is incorrect, yours is clearly a better answer).

Comment: Sorry, but I had to choose a good answer. Another +1 on your insightful comment to be as fair as possible, I hope you understand.

Comment: No need to apologize - Evan's answer is definitely better. There's no need to apologize even if that weren't the case.

Answer (score 1):

All preprocessor directives are interpreted before macro expansion begins, so no, you cannot have a macro expand into an #include directive and have it be interpreted as such.  Instead, it will be interpreted as (erroneous) C++ code.

Comment: You might get this impression because many directives disable macro expansion of their arguments, but this is not true.  Macro expansion happens concurrently with directive parsing.  If it were true, #if would not work, and #undef would not have the effect people expect.