# define macro expanded to literal #

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ preprocessor macro expansion to another preprocessor directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262063/c-preprocessor-macro-expansion-to-another-preprocessor-directive)

My question is very simple: I want to use "#" in the macro expansion, for example, to define a marco 'M(X)':

```
#define M(X) #ifdef FOO \ 
              X=1 \
             #else \ 
              X=2
```

I tried to use '\' to escape the '#', but the '\' is interpreted as the newline for macro expansion, and not as the escape character. 
So how to use '#' in the macro expansion?

Thanks folks!

Comment: You should accept whichever answer you found helpful. (Click the checkmark and turn it green.)

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, but you cannot have a macro emit another macro because the pre-processor is single pass. Also from the c99 standard:

(6.10.3.4 paragraph 3):

> 3 The resulting completely
>   macro-replaced preprocessing token
>   sequence is not processed as a
>   preprocessing directive even if it
>   resembles one, ...

c++ has something similar as well.

Comment: Didnt expect a reply so fast and accurate, salute!

Answer (score 6):

You could do the opposite:

```
#ifdef FOO
    #define M(X) X=1
#else
    #define M(X) X=2
#endif
```

Comment: +1, Seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: Your solution fits my need perfect, applause!

Answer (score 1):

As @Evan points out, macro expansion is done in a single pass, so your example will not work. However, here is an alternative that does what you want, albeit in a few more lines.

```
#ifdef FOO
#define FOOVAL 1
#else
#define FOOVAL 2
#endif

#define M(X) X=FOOVAL
```